# Apache Camel Drill component issue with credentials and setup

Tags: apache-camel, credentials, apache-drill

I'm tinkering a little with Apache Camel, specifically, I'd like to connect it and query an hive database via Apache Drill. I'm struggling with something very simple as "how to pass credentials" to the driver.

I've read the doc online https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/drill-component.html, checked examples online, but could not find any hint that would point me in the right direction.

The version I'm using the latest apache camel on Quarkus.

Comment: it looks like there's nonreal option, mind opening an issue ?

Comment: I do not, at all.